# $W$ be a $d$-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb R^n$. Then how to show that $|\{(x_1,...,x_n) \in W : x_i \in \{0,1\}\}| \le 2^d$?

Tags: linear-algebra, elementary-set-theory, vector-spaces

Let $W$ be a $d$-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb R^n$. Then how to show that $|\{(x_1,...,x_n) \in W : x_i \in \{0,1\}\}| \le 2^d$ ?

I can see that we are done if we can find an injective function from $\{(x_1,...,x_n) \in W : x_i \in \{0,1\}\}$ to $\mathbb F_2^d $ , but I can't quite see any such natural injection.

Comment: Looking quickly: can't you prove it by induction on $d$, using some combinatorics?

Comment: @IvoTerek: counting may be possible but I don't quite see it (please post it as an answer if you work it out fully ... ) ... finding an injective function might be more elegant :) ...

Comment: I don't understand the meaning of close vote ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $S$ is any set let $\Bbb R^S$ denote the vector space of all functions from $S$ to $\Bbb R$. Regard $\Bbb R^n$ as $\Bbb R^{\{1,2,\dots,n\}}$.

Now if $S\subset\{1,2\dots,n\}$ there is a natural linear map $$T_S:\Bbb R^n\to \Bbb R^S$$defined by $$T_Sx=x|_S.$$

(To perhaps clarify, less formally: If $d=3$ and $S=\{1,3\}$ one might regard $T_S$ as defined by $T_S(x_1,x_2,x_3)=(x_1,x_3)$.)

Note this:

> > **Note:** If $W$ is a subspace of dimension $d$ then there exists $S\subset\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ such that $|S|=d$ and the restriction of $T_S$ to $W$ is *injective*.

Inelegant "proof": Say $A$ is a matrix that has the elements of a basis for $W$ as rows. Then $A$ has rank $d$; let $S$ consist of the indices where an echelon form for $A$ has pivots...

One might add a few details, but that certainly seems right. If so then there's your injective map from your set to $\{0,1\}^d$.

**Edit:** Ok, a somewhat more detailed proof of the Note above: Let $A$ be a $d\times n$ matrix such that the rows of $A$ form a basis for $W$. Since the row rank equals the column rank, $A$ has $d$ independent columns. Say $C_j(A)$ is the $j$th column of $A$. Say $|S|=d$ and $\{C_j(A):j\in S\}$ is independent. Let $D$ be the square matrix with columns precisely $C_j(A)$ for $j\in S$. Then $D$ is a $d\times d$ matrix of rank $d$, so $D$ is invertible, and hence the rows of $D$ are independent.

So: Starting with a basis $b_1,\dots,b_d$ for $W$ we have found $S$ with $|S|=d$ such that $T_Sb_1,\dots,T_Sb_d$ are independent. Hence the restriction of $T_S$ to $W$ is injective.

Comment: in your definition of $T_S$, should that be $\mathbb R$ ? And I still don't see how do we get the injective map from your "note" ... is there no connection between $S$ and $d$ ?

Comment: @misao Should _what_ be $\Bbb R$? Typo: I left out the condition that $|S|=d$, sorry.

Comment: @misao Now since $T_S$ is injective on all of $W$ it is injective on the subset you ask about. And it maps your set into $\{0,1\}^S$, which has cardinality $2^d$.

Comment: thanks ... and how to choose such $S$ with $|S|=d$ ?

Comment: @misao Exactly as I said! $S$ is the set of indices where an echelon form for $A$ has pivots.

Comment: can't it be done without matrices ?

Comment: @misao Note I added a more detailed proof of the Note. Can't it be done without matrices? That would be nice, but perhaps not. Because the question itself deals with the _entries_ in vectors, instead of being a pure coordinate-free linear-algebra sort of thing. (The more detailed version of the proof does avoid mentioning echelon forms. It depends on the fact that the row rank is the same as the column rank, which alas is clear _from_ the echelon form...)

Answer (score 3):

This is essentially the same argument as David C. Ullrich's, but explained without matrices:

We would like to show that elements of $W$ are determined by $d$ well-chosen, fixed, projections $p_i$ out of the $n$ natural projections $\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$. I.e. we want that the intersection of the $\ker p_i$ intersects $W$ trivially. Put differently, we want an $n-d$-dimensional subspace spanned by $n-d$ standard basis elements, which is complementary to $W$.

We can generalize the result we need as follows:

**Proposition.** Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space, $\dim V = n$, and $W \subseteq V$ a subspace, $\dim W = d$. Let $U \subseteq V$ be a set that spans $V$ together with $W$. Then there exist $n-d$ elements in $U$ that span a subspace complementary to $W$.

*Proof 1.* By induction on $n-d$: For $d=n$ there is nothing to prove. Suppose $d < n$, then because $W \neq V$ there exists $u \in U - W$. Apply the induction hypothesis to $W' = W + \langle u \rangle$ and $U' = U - \{u\}$, and note that $\dim W' = d + 1$. $\square$

*Proof 2.* Quotienting everything by $W$, this simply says that if $U$ (actually: its image in the quotient) spans $V/W$, then it contains a basis of $V/W$. $\square$

It suffices to apply this for $V = \mathbb R^n$, $W=W$ and $U$ the standard basis.

Comment: Great. Wouldn't "...if $U/W$ spans $V/W$..." be better than "...if $U$ spans..."?

Comment: I added some clarification. I'm not sure about writing $U/W$ if $U$ is not a subspace or if $W \nsubseteq U$ (but I like the notation)